# subsetting a vector/data frame in R yields different results

Tags: r, subset

Recently, I was asked about subsetting a data frame in R. My colleague had this line of code

`dd2 <- subset(dd, tret == c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"))` which yields 1/4 of the subset. In contrast to the standard `dd2 <- subset(dd, tret == "T1" | tret == "T2" | tret == "T3" | tret == "T4")` which yields 960 rows, the first line of code only yields 240 rows.

Same thing happens to vectors. For instance,

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
y <- x[x == 1 | x == 2] gives a vector different from 
y <- x[x == c(1,2)]
```

Any insight on the differences? Thank you.

Comment: Because `==` works when the rhs is of length 1.  There is recycling i.e. the first value of x is compared with 1, then 2nd with 2, 3rd with 1, 4th with 2, .... Use `%in%` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the recycling of values when we use a `vector` with `length` greater than 1 with another one having `length` > 1.

```
x == 1:2
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

where

```
x
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

and the comparison works in the following way

```
rep(1:2, length.out = length(x))
#[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

In the above example, 1 is compared to the first element of x, 2 with 2nd element, 1 again with 3rd element of x, 2 with 4th, and it repeats until the end of the vector 'x'.  For comparing vectors of length > 1, use `%in%`

```
identical(x[x == 1 | x == 2], x[x %in% 1:2])
#[1] TRUE
```